# Javascript hide/show div based on the day of the week?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an dynamic page that changes content based on the day of the week. I thought I had the solution, but I can't seem to make it work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showhide(id) {
    var d = new Date();
    var s = document.getElementById[d.getDay()];
    s.style.display = (s.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:showhide[d.getDay()]">
<div id="0" style="display:none;">
     <h3>Sunday</h3>

</div>
<div id="1" style="display:none;">
     <h3>Monday</h3>

</div>
<div id="2" style="display:none">
     <h3>Tuesday</h3>

</div>
<div id="3" style="display:none">
     <h3>Wednesday</h3>

</div>
<div id="4" style="display:none">
     <h3>Thursday</h3>

</div>
<div id="5" style="display:none">
     <h3>Friday</h3>

</div>
<div id="6" style="display:none">
     <h3>Saturday</h3>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect it's either something really simple and I'm way overthinking it, or it's something that I just haven't grasped yet. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

My sources so far have been w3schools, jsfiddle, and here (I borrowed a snippet of my code from another post here).

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly there, change document.getElementById[] to document.getElementById() & add the script to the bottom of the page(below your markup and just before the '' tag) and you can remove the body onload event and just call the function as below:

```
...
<div id="6" style="display:none">
   <h3>Saturday</h3>

</div>
<script>
  function showhide() {
    var d = new Date();
    var s = document.getElementById(+d.getDay());
    s.style.display = (s.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
  }
  showhide();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/wyoffLw6/

By calling the function at the bottom of the page(after your markup) you are effective triggering the function when all the elements on the page have loaded

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! this answer worked extremely effectively. I will definitely be saving this little gem.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has 2 problems.

First problem, it seems like you're mixing up **[]** and **()**

- **[]** is used to **access** elements in arrays or properties in objects
- **()** is used to **invoke** functions

Second problem, you are trying to use the `d` variable in your HTML even though it is only available in your `showhide` function (variables declared inside a function are only available within this function and it's children).

Therefore **to fix your code you should**:

Replace `document.getElementById[d.getDay()];` with `document.getElementById(d.getDay());`

And in your HTML replace `<body onload="javascript:showhide[d.getDay()]">` with `<body onload="showhide()">`

Finally depending on what you want to achieve, you should consider if you really need to create the DOM elements for each days or if you could inject only the data you need like so:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function injectDay() {
        var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
          'Friday', 'Saturday'];
        var date = new Date();

        document.querySelector('.dayContainer').innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="injectDay()">
    <div>
      <h3 class="dayContainer"></h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myDay() {
        var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
        var date = new Date();
        document.querySelector('.dayname').innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];

        if(date.getDay()%2!=0){
             document.querySelector('.dayname2').innerHTML = days[date.getDay()-1];
             document.querySelector('.dayname3').innerHTML = days[date.getDay()+1];
            document.querySelector('.dayname').innerHTML = ""; //same hide
       }else{
             document.querySelector('.dayname').innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];
              document.querySelector('.dayname2').innerHTML = days[date.getDay()-2];
             document.querySelector('.dayname3').innerHTML = days[date.getDay()+2];  
       } 
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body onload="myDay()">  
       <table>
         <tr>
             <td class="dayname2" id ="AA">
             </td>
             <td class="dayname">
             </td>
             <td class="dayname3">
             </td>
         </tr>
      </table>        
  </body>
</html>
```