# Random generator click one per day

Tags: javascript, random, generator

I've added a modal with random content (text + image) by clicking a simple link and it works great!
But now I'm stuck 'cause I want it to show the same content for 24 hours, no matter how many times users click the link... A quote per day: that would be my point to avoid tons of click from users. Somebody can help me?

```js
(function() {
  var quotes = [{
    text: "...",
    img: "..."
  }, {
    text: "...",
    img: "...",
  }];
  var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
    '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
    '<img src="' + quote.img + '">';
})();
```

Comment: Why not use some localstorage or cookies (with expiry)? to store the user choice. As such you can always check the value in your preferred storage, if it exists and has not expired you show that value (and probably disable the link).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript hide/show div based on the day of the week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015489/javascript-hide-show-div-based-on-the-day-of-the-week)

Comment: Just to be clear; you want to memorize the selection per user?

Comment: For example, `Math.floor(Date.now() / 86400) % quotes.length` is guaranteed to always return the same quote throughout a single day.

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă That worked great! Now I have different random posts per user but ever the same! I'm gonna click again tomorrow to check things out but I think that was the trick! Thank you, very very very much! I've been stucked on there for hours! Thank you! ♥

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă Are you sure it's guaranteed? I ran a test on a couple of Date objects (for a future date) with the same day but different times and I got different values using your suggestion as soon as the time changed significantly (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynq8mab4/)). Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Also, that's not a solution *per user*, it's a general solution that will display the same quote to *all users*.

Comment: @El_Vanja My bad, `Date.getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds, try 86400000, ie. 3 more zeroes to convert seconds to milliseconds.

Comment: @El_Vanja That's weird... I've tried with different users and they seems to get their random content (different stuff for everyone) but ever the same to every click...

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă That makes sense. Should've figured it out myself. @LeeScott How exactly have you implemented it? Just `var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Date.now() / 86400) % quotes.length]` or something extra?

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes, I've only replaced my var quote with ` var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Date.now() / 86400) % quotes.length] ` and it seems to work. Now some users get A, others get B but they still get their A or their B on multiple clicks...

Comment: @LeeScott See my above comment as to why you have to replace 86400 with 86400000 (i.e. replace the number of seconds in a day with the number of milliseconds in a day, since `Date.getTime()` returns milliseconds.

Comment: Do your users perhaps have different timezones?

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă OK, sadly, problems popped! The replacement actually provide the content to be the same even on tons on click... but now it is the same for all the users... ç.ç

Comment: @El_Vanja No, we all got the same timezone... This random thing is going to make me crazy...

Comment: The code you posted is javascript but you also tagged the question java and php, can you solve it with either? Otherwise please edit the tags.

Comment: You just can't get different *random* outputs *per user* without some kind of storage.

Comment: If you don't have your visitors log in and thus no way of identifying them across browsers and devices, you might just use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store which random quote was picked for the day. The limitation will obviously be that if the access the site with multiple browser/devices/etc. they will get different quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your case pseudo-random is enough.

So you could use something like:

`Random generator = new Random(seed);`

instead of Math.random() and for the seed you'll use the current date. That way the selection will appear to be random but also fixed for the day.

If you need a pseudo-random selection for each user you could just add the username to the seed as well.

Comment: I realize your question is tagged `javascript`, `java` and `php`. I was looking for unanswered java questions and got here, misleading tags.

Comment: I'm really sorry. This was my first question on Stack Overflow and I'm still learning about the site and the coding too, so I apologize for the misleading tags. Could you please teach/tell me how exactly implement Random generator and the current date to my code...? I don't even know where to start... I do thank you for your help and the patience.

Comment: I don't think there is a "random" number generator which can be initialized with a seed to return predictable results in JavaScript. Usually these pseudo-random number generators are avoided anyway because they're not cryptographically secure (in your case that wouldn't have mattered). I think you'll have to use some storage like others suggested.